# I don't understand the 2-51-7024 MCI transformer specs

Tags: transformer

What kind of transformer is this: [2-51-7024](https://mcitransformer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/2-51-7024.pdf) (from [this site](https://mcitransformer.com/product/chassis-mount-ul-class-2-transformers/))?

I am looking for a cheaper alternative, and don't understand the specs - is it an AC to AC transformer?

Comment: You do not appear to have read the data sheet. There is a circuit diagram of the transformer that tells you at a glance exactly what type of transformer it is.

Comment: What other type of transformer is there? You can't put DC into a transformer, or get DC out of one, without adding extra circuitry to turn the DC into AC or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

It is an AC power transformer with a laminated steel core of the E-I design. Is has primary connections for 120, 208 and 240 volts and a secondary connection for 24 volts. It is rated 80 VA. 50/68 Hz. It is UL listed as a class 2 transformer - not wet and class 3 wet. It is internally protected by a thermal fuse in the primary. Most of that is documented on the web page linked in the question or the PDF linked to that page. The core design is evident in the photo and drawing. The meaning of UL classes is explained by [this white paper](https://belfuse.com/resources/whitepaper/signaltransformer/wp-ST-Class-vs-Class.pdf).

The [Wikipedia Transformer article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) should also be helpful.